Wo befindet sich die „wichtigste Information" im Satz?
Ich habe vor einer Weile gelesen, dass die wichtigste Information in einem deutschen Satz sich am Ende des Satzes befindet.  Aber ein Lehrer hat mir gesagt, nein, sie kommt am Anfang.  Es kann sein, dass keines korrekt ist.  Aber wenn es so ist, dass die wichtige Information am Ende steht, dann könnte man vielleicht glauben, dass das ein Grund dafür wäre, wieso Nebensätze oft das Verb am Ende haben.  Und auch, wo man andere Wörter stellen sollte, um die richtige Betonung, bzw. Bedeutung dem Satz zu verleihen. Sowieso würde ich es interessant finden, das zu wissen.

Bei den meisten Sätzen ist tatsächlich die wichtigste Information am Ende.
Das ist das Neue, das Überraschende. Aber der Anfang spielt auch eine wichtige Rolle: Er macht klar, über was du redest. Startest du einen Satz mit "Ich habe gestern...", ist dem Hörer sofort klar, über was du redest: Du redest über dich und über gestern. Viel neues steckt da aber nicht drin. Das passiert erst, wenn du mit "(Ich habe gestern...) Fußball geschaut", den Satz beendest.
Aber ob jetzt der Anfang oder das Ende wichtiger ist, ist Ansichtsache. Man könnte sagen: Was bringt es mir zu wissen, dass irgendwer irgendwann Fußball geschaut hat? Außerdem – wenn man sich die Handlung im Satz anschaut, bist du ja am wichtigsten, weil du etwas getan hast.
Es gibt nun einige Sätze, wo das wichtigste direkt am Anfang ist: In einer Antwort ist der wichtigste Teil gleich am Anfang.

Wer hat gestern Fußball geschaut? 
Ich habe gestern Fußball geschaut.

In einer Antwort willst du normalerweise die Information so schnell wie möglich sagen, deshalb ist sie am Anfang. Die Betonung ist nun anders als bei normalen Sätzen: Da der Rest schon bekannt ist, fällt nach der Information die Betonung schnell ab. Es gibt noch einen anderen Fall, wo der wichtigste Teil direkt am Anfang ist, bei einem Kontrast:

Ute habe ich gesehen, aber Beate nicht.

Dein Lehrer könnte also etwas anderes unter "wichtige Information" verstehen, oder an die zwei besonderen Arten von Sätzen gedacht haben.

So wie die Frage gestellt ist, ist sie schwer eindeutig zu beantworten.
Man könnte argumentieren, daß das Prädikat das Wichtigste im Satz sei, denn es gibt zwar Sätze ohne Subjekt:

Mir ist kalt.
Iß auf!

aber keine ohne Prädikat.
Andererseits sind - da hat @Dodezv völlig recht - sowohl der Anfang als auch das Ende eines Satzes hervorgehobene Positionen, die besondere Bedeutungen tragen. Der simple Satz "ich gehe morgen fischen" könnte auch so formuliert werden:

Fischen gehe ich morgen.

Da wäre aber das "fischen" und das "morgen" besonders betont. In der Form könnte der Satz etwa in diesem Kontext stehen:

Heute ist mir nach Schwimmen und das mache ich auch den ganzen Tag, aber Fischen, Fischen gehe ich morgen.


Wenn man sagt "die wichtigste Information", dann ist das recht unscharf, es gibt verschiedene Hinsichten, wie etwas wichtig sein kann. Daher entsteht glaub ich die Frage.

Es gibt die sogenannte Thema-Rhema-Gliederung. Das bedeutet, dass der gesamte Satz in 2 Zonen eingeteilt ist: Information, die als bekannt zählt, die im Kontext schon unterwegs ist und an die man anschließt - und dagegen die neue Information. In Bezug auf diese Aufteilung steht das Bekannte im ersten Teil des Satzes, "das Wichtige" im Sinne von "das Neue" hinten im Satz.
Es gibt Kontrastbetonung und Fokus. Ein betonter Satzteil ist als "wichtig" markiert in dem Sinn, dass Alternativen dazu aufgerufen werden (meist um abgelehnt zu werden, im Gegensatz zur Aussage, die man macht). Satzteile, die eine Kontrastbetonung tragen, können nach vorne versetzt werden, und gerne wird auch das Vorfeld (die Anfangsposition) dafür benutzt.

Beispiel: Frage: "Wem hat er das Geld gegeben? – Antwort:

"Er hat das Geld ... dem Pizzaboten gegeben." ("Pizzabote" ist die neue Information, das Geld ist in der Frage schon vorerwähnt).
"Dem PIZZABOTEN hat er das Geld gegeben!" (Ausruf im Sinne von: unglaublich, das war ein Fehler)

Besonders dann, wenn man etwas ausdrücken will wie im Kommentar zum zweiten Beispiel, kann man den Pizzaboten hinstellen wo man will, aber er muss eine deutliche Betonung tragen. Das ist nun Kontrast-Fokus. Im ersten Beispiel ist Pizzabote auch leicht betont, aber hier handelt es sich auch um die normale Betonungsstelle für einen Aussagesatz, die auch gewählt wird, wenn nichts hervorgehoben werden soll. – Generell soll man nie vergessen, dass man bei schriftlichen Beispielen die Intonation und Betonung als Leser erst erraten muss, somit fehlt aber Information, die für die Wortstellung im Deutschen wichtig ist.
Die Position des Prädikats am Satzende oder in der Zweitposition wird von solchen Stellungs-, Betonungs- bzw Hervorhebungsregeln nicht betroffen, weil sie grammatisch festgelegt ist. Nur die anderen Satzteile sind im Deutschen beliebig verschiebbar. Die Regel "neue Information kommt später im Satz" soll also heißen, sie kommt in der Zone vor der Verb-End-Position, aber die Verbbposition selbst ist rein grammatisch festgelegt.

Ich möchte deine Frage wie folgt beantworten: Wo die wichtigste Information steht, bestimmt der Sprecher und der Kontext.
Begründung:
Ist es möglich, dass du eine Muttersprache wie Japanisch sprichst?
Da steht das Thema des Satzes in der Regel zu Beginn des Satzes und wird durch ein sogenanntes Partikel は (Ha) gekennzeichnet.
So ein grammatikalisches Konzept gibt es im Deutschen nicht.
Dazu kommt, dass du durch die deutschen Fälle Sätze umfangreich umstellen kannst.
Beispielsweise drücken beide folgenden Sätze das gleiche aus:
Die Hand streichelt den Hund.
Den Hund streichelt die Hand.
Auch das Verb lässt sich verschieben.
Der Hund wird von der Hand gestreichelt.
Von der Hand wird der Hund gestreichelt.
